# Cable thickness for solar borehole pump

Tags: voltage, current, current-measurement

I have a solar borehole pump: 24 volts - 270 watts panels (two x 135W). I want to move my panels 300 to 350 meters away from the borehole, reducing the risk of theft. What size of cable should I use given the distance? The wire will run in PVC conduit pipe underground. Ambient temperature during the summer: 30 - 40 degrees celsius.

Comment: A quick glance at wire tables suggests that unacceptable power loss may be more of a limiting factor than overheating the wire.  Your distances seem to be into the territory where the complexity of stepping up to a higher voltage might be worthwhile, compared to burying large amounts of expensive copper.  It's unclear that your transmission system will cost less than the panels you are trying to protect.

Comment: Seconded. According to PowerStream, a 4AWG conductor has roughly 0.2485 ohms per 1000 feet.  That's 0.285775 ohms for your 350 meter run.  At 24VDC, your pumps require about ~11.5A.  ~11.5A over 350 meters of 4AWG wire incurs about a ~3.3V drop.  Since you have to make the return back over the ground wire, the voltage loss is double... now you've dropped ~6.6V from your 24VDC supply.  Now, two 4AWG conductors is pretty hefty, as well as costly.  You could easily pay $1 USD per foot.  That's over $2,000 USD just for the wire and your voltage drop is still high even with these big conductors....

Answer (score 3):

The question is really whether it is worth transforming that power up to 240V to cover the distance.

You can establish the feasibility of 24V transmission using Ohm's Law :

[This page](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/copper-wire-d_1429.html) gives the resistance of 2000 feet of 8awg (10mm^2) wire as approaching 1.5 ohms. At 10 amps, that implies a drop of 15v leaving only 9v to run the pump.

Now, price out 2000ft of 8awg ... I'm seeing [£130 for 100m](http://uk.farnell.com/lapp-kabel/4520005/wire-h07v-k-grn-yel-10mm-100m/dp/1204359) in 5 or more, or about £650 for the length you need. You can probably do better but thicker wire would be more expensive...
I think you can probably afford a 240V inverter for that sort of money, and save money on cable as well as reducing I^2R losses.

To flesh that out a little, at 1 amp those 8awg cables would drop 1.5 volts : that's less than 1% of your 240V supply. So use thinner cables; lose 10V (4%) or so but you'll lose maybe 10% in the inverter anyway. The reduced price of the thinner cables will pay for the inverter. This is looking like a better solution.